# iterate associate array in php does not print out values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying out the following code for arrays in php, I create a associate array, print out the values and add one more to the array - print out again. This works, but if I try the `foreach ($MovieCollection as $key => $value)` it does not print out the values. Why does it not do that?

```
$myArray = array("Star Wars", "The Shining");

foreach ($myArray as $val)
{
    echo("Movie: " . $val ."<br>");
}


$MovieCollection = array();
$MovieCollection[] = array('title' => 'Star Wars', 'description'     =>'classic');

foreach ($MovieCollection as $film )
{
    echo($film['title'] .": " . $film['description'] ."<br>");
}
$MovieCollection[] = array('title' => 'The shinning', 'description'         =>'creepy');


foreach ($MovieCollection as $film )
{
    echo($film['title'] .": " . $film['description'] ."<br>");
}
echo("<br><br>");
// This does not print the values?
foreach ($MovieCollection as $key => $value)
{
    echo($key .": " . $value ."<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because in this part `$MovieCollection` is an array of arrays and if you want to echo the `$value` which is an array, you will do  an `Array to string conversion` which does not work.

What you might do is use another foreach to show the values per array:

```
foreach ($MovieCollection as $value) {
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        echo($k .": " . $v ."<br>");
    }
}
```

See a [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/3erMQ)